# I am able to re-use the same tracking ID of Google Analytics on other website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics to track traffic and page views on my website. The thing that is weird is that I copied the code (JS) to another website with another domain name and it started tracking that other website. When it is not supposed too...

Is there a way to limit my Google Analytic tracking ID to only track only one website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA sends the domain along with the request, so you should be able to specify a filter in your reports to only include specific domains in the reports.

Comment: SHouldn't by default limit to the one domain?

Comment: No (for one that would make cross domain tracking quite difficult).  A filter is the way to go.

Comment: @jnbdz: As Eike mentioned, a lot of companies buy subdomains/mirror domains  which would make GA fail. for instance, google.com, gooogle.com (extra o), google.co.uk, google.net, etc.